# take user input from a grouped dataframe and plot graph

Tags: pandas, dataframe, csv, matplotlib, pandas-groupby

> I have CSV data with IP Addresses and corresponding Timestamp when it was hit. This I have arranged in a Dataframe

```
        IP_Address                Time
       1xx.1xx.1xx.xx        2020-06-30 23:48:37
       1xx.6x.2xx.1xx        2020-06-30 23:48:37
            ...                 ...
       xx.2xx.xxx.xx         2020-07-01 06:25:42
```

I want to plot a graph of a particular IP address, taken from user as input, and then plot the number of times it was hit at different time intervals. Meaning, for a given IP address :

on X-axis, I want the different timestamps when the IP was called and

on Y-axis, I want the number of times that IP was called for a given value of time on X-axis.

[image]

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Spyder Editor

This is a temporary script file.
"""

import csv
import pandas as pd
import datetime
#from time import mktime
from datetime import datetime

# read the CSV file using csv.reader method of CSV module and print the lines in a list
with open ('File1_csv.txt') as csvfile:

    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

    ipaddress = []
    time = []
    for lines in readCSV:
        #(lines[1] , lines[18] , lines[20])
        ipaddress.append(lines[20])
        dt_object = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(lines[1]))
       # dt_object1=dt_object.strftime("%d %m %Y")
      #  print("dt_object =" , dt_object1)
        #print("type(dt_object) =" , type(dt_object))
        time.append(dt_object)

    #print(ipaddress)
    #print(time)

#from pandas import DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame ({'IP_Address' : ipaddress  , 'Time' : time})
print(df)
x = df['Time'].value_counts()
print(x)
y = df['IP_Address'].value_counts()
print(y)

input_ip = input("Enter the IP Address to see the number of pings")
print(input_ip)

import matplotlib as plot

#df_graph = pd.DataFrame ({'Time' : time  , 'Date Count' : df['Time'].value_counts()})
#df['Time'].value_counts()[:20].plot(x ='Time', y='IP Address Hits',kind='bar')
#df['IP_Address'].value_counts()[:20].plot(x = 'IP' , y = 'IP Address Hits' , kind ='bar')
df['input_ip'].plot(x = 'IP' , y = 'IP Address Hits' , kind ='bar')

    #gb = df.groupby(ipaddress).count()
    #print(df)
#print(df_graph) code here
```

Comment: and what is the problem?

Comment: then you need to group you data by ip then loop over each group and plot data

Comment: `df[df.eq(input_ip).any(1)]` this statement worked without the need for a **group by**

Answer (score 0):

`df[df.eq(input_ip).any(1)]` this statement worked without the need for a group by